# Get input array of particular type

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to get array input in particular types - example for int below.

```
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] array = new array[input.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
   array[i] = int.Parse(input[i]);
}
```

This is working, but in case of multiple such arrays of different type it takes up too much code to get input in string array and then parse it into required type for every input array.
Is there any shortcut way to get this done ?
It is guaranteed that complete array input will lie on single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__):

```
int[] array = input.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

You could easily change this to another type, for example:

```
class StringContainer
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

StringContainer[] array = input.Select(x => new StringContainer { Value = x }).ToArray();
```

You could even define an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static TOut[] Convert<TIn, TOut>(this TIn[] input, Func<TIn, TOut> selector)
{
    return input.Select(selector).ToArray();
}
```

Then use like this:

```
int[] intArray = input.Convert(int.Parse);
StringContainer[] scArray = input.Convert(x => new StringContainer { Value = x });
```

The type of the output array is inferred from the return type of the delegate.